# How to scrape actualstarttime field from this source code

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I want to scrape the actual start time through the Nokogiri gem.

```or-tag-here
<dl class="dates">
   <dt>Actual Start Date &amp; Time:</dt>
   <dd class="date " >
      <span data-name="Actual Start Date &amp; Time" id="customfield_10207-val"  data-fieldtype="datetime" >
      <span title="19/Feb/14 3:14 PM">
      <time datetime="2014-02-19T15:14+0000">19/Feb/14 3:14 PM</time>
      </span>
      </span>
   </dd>
</dl>
```

Can anybody take a look and let me know what css rule i need to apply to scrape?

Comment: what value you want from there ?

Comment: @arupRakshit -19/Feb/14 3:14 PM

Comment: The answer is the start time is simply `2014-02-19T15:14+0000`, but that’s probably not what you’re asking. What node to you want to extract? Is it the `date` element that is a child of the span with id `customfield_10207-val` - will that id always have that value? Otherwise can you rely on the page having a unique element with a `data-name` attribute with the value `Actual Start Date &amp; Time` then you could use that. Perhaps that isn’t the case either, but the date you’re after will always be part of the first `dd` element of the only `dl` with class dates? Or something else?

Comment: am trying to extract 19/Feb/14 3:14 PM

Comment: @user2694406 okay, then here’s your answer: `19/Feb/14 3:14 PM` :-). My point is you want that value _because it is at some particular position in the document_. So what is that position, how would you describe it without just saying what its contents are? Because in general you won’t know the contents.

Comment: @matt -resolved by -starttime = details.at_css("#customfield_10214-val").at_css("time").text.strip

Comment: @user2694406 in your question the id is `customfield_10207-val`, but you say you are using `customfield_10214-val`, which is different. This is why I asked if the id will always have that value. Are you sure you can always get the value you want using that id – will it change again in the future leaving your code not working?

Comment: @matt in the page where am trying to scrape two timings were there 1.schedule time and actual start time . and the id remains constant respectively. so in this case  i choose schedule time which id is "customfield_10207-val". But in question have asked for the actual time and cane be done by picking "customfield_10207-val"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<_
<dl class="dates">
  <dt>
    Actual Start Date &amp; Time:
  </dt>
  <dd class="date " >

    <span data-name="Actual Start Date &amp; Time" id="customfield_10207-val"  data-fieldtype="datetime" >
      <span title="19/Feb/14 3:14 PM">
        <time datetime="2014-02-19T15:14+0000">
          19/Feb/14 3:14 PM
        </time>
      </span>
    </span>
  </dd>
</dl>
_

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

Now, you can take out the time using two different kinds of CSS rules. I used [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css), as I am interested with the first node that would match the CSS rules. But your requirement is to collect more than one node which would match the CSS rule, so use the method [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css). It will give you the [`Nodeset`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which will hold all the nodes that matched your CSS rule. Now you can use [`each`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-each) method to iterate each node from the Nodeset collection.

```
date = doc.at_css('#customfield_10207-val > span')['title']
date # => "19/Feb/14 3:14 PM"
date = doc.at_css('#customfield_10207-val > span > time').text.strip
date # => "19/Feb/14 3:14 PM"
```

Please browse [CSS3/Selectors](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors) to understand the CSS rules.

Comment: I will explain it also.. preparing another SO post answer.. :-)

Comment: Haha.. Yea, you must multitask if you wish to be the first to answer :-)

Comment: Thank you arup for the detailed explanation but still in my enviroment   still not able to scrape.

Comment: resolved by -starttime = details.at_css("#customfield_10214-val").at_css("time").text.strip

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

source = open('http://www.example.com/time.html')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(source) 
doc.css('dd.date time').first.content

=> "19/Feb/14 3:14 PM"
```

Comment: Use `doc.at('dd.date time').content` instead. `at` returns the first matching node. `css` is equivalent to `search` and returns a NodeSet, which forces you to use `first`.

Comment: @theTinMan I went with `.css` (and avoided targeting the ID selector) to illustrate that the poster could get them all on a page that has many, but this is a good thing to note.